# getting photos from facebook real time updates

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, real-time, photo

I would like to know if there is a way to receive a real time update when a user (who granted my apps needed rights) post a photo in an album, in a group, or share photo on his/her status updates.

Looking at facebook docs, I was under the impression I could only get update if the user change his/her the profile photo.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/.
It doesn't show you exactly which attributes you can monitor with real time updates but there is an autocomplete in the Facebook Developer interface that shows you things like:

```
name, category, location, phone, checkins, picture, website, hours, company_overview, description, email, feed, founded, features, general_info, general_manager, hometown, products, parking, public_transit, payment_options, price_range, restaurant_services, restaurant_specialties, culinary_team, press_contact, personal_info, personal_interests, productlists, awards, booking_agent, affiliation, bio, birthday, built, genre
```

This does not include new photos.. but you might be able to monitor those using 'feed'.